# Simple sql multi-table query

Tags: php, sql

I am programming a chat room on my site but I am really new to php. I want users to be able to chat with the users that played in the same teams of a game (knowing that users can have participated together to differents team) and who work in the same area.

Assume there are three tables : the account user's table, the area's t  able, games'table

I have a function that returns my query that looks like

```
function myfunction($userid){

$games_user=mysql_query('select theme from games where games.userid="'.$userid.'"');  
$games_theme = mysql_fetch_array($games_user);

$sql = ("select  userid, username, area.userid 

    from account 
        left join area
            on account.userid = area.userid    

        left join games
            on account.userid = games.userid

    where account.userid <> '".mysql_real_escape_string($userid)."' and '".(in_array(games.theme,$games_theme))."' and area.userid=1 
 );
 return $sql;
}
```

*Reformatted:*

```
$sql = "
SELECT userid, username, area.userid 
FROM account 
LEFT JOIN area ON account.userid = area.userid    
LEFT JOIN games ON account.userid = games.userid
WHERE account.userid <> '".mysql_real_escape_string($userid)."'
  AND '".(in_array(games.theme,$games_theme))."'
  AND area.userid = 1 
";
```

But it really doesn't work, I think I have syntax problems. 
 I don't really understand how in_array is indexed, and I don't know how to do in a simpler way that query

Can anybody help ?

Comment: You are arbitrarily sticking the PHP function `in_array()` into a query.  What are you trying to accomplish with that? Looks like you want to know if the column value `games.theme` matches one of the values in the `$games_theme` array, which was a row fetched from your first query?

Comment: You should be able to tell by the code highlighting you've got something wrong syntax-wise (it's a missing `"` at the end). Do yourself a favor and work on your query formatting; what you have is hard to read compared to [what it should be](http://codepad.org/XZOKwncG), IMO.

Comment: if `userid` is stored as integer, there's no need to do `'.."' . $userid . '"'`.

Comment: Also, looking at your [reformatted query](http://codepad.org/XZOKwncG), @Michael is right; you *probably* want a [MYSQL keyword or function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html); `in_array()` is PHP.

Comment: to be more precise : you have a userid parameter, this user participated to numbers of themes'games and I want to fetch all the users who participated to the same themes and who an area's id of one. So I fetch in account's table all the users, then I cross it with those who have an area's id of one, and finally I cross the latte result with all themes'users who participated to the same $users(parameter)'s themes. Am I clear ? Is my query not adapted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not entirely sure what you are doing, but I think this is what you want; you can do this in a single query:

```
<?php
function myfunction($userid){
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($userid);
    $sql = "SELECT  userid, username, area.userid 
        FROM account 
            LEFT JOIN area
                ON account.userid = area.userid    
            LEFT JOIN games
                ON account.userid = games.userid
        WHERE account.userid<>'$id' AND area.userid=1
            AND games.theme IN (SELECT theme FROM games WHERE games.userid='$id')
    ";
    return $sql;
}
?>
```